# openvpn stuck at systemd-tty-ask-password-agent

Tags: vpn, openvpn, systemd

trying to start openvpn and I keep getting this:

```
Broadcast message from root@Media (Thu 2017-08-03 07:28:29 EDT):

Password entry required for 'Enter Auth Password:' (PID 31285).
Please enter password with the systemd-tty-ask-password-agent tool!
```

If I keep the openvpn process running I can type in that command,  but whatever i put into the username it takes, then does nothing...it just drops me back to the terminal line.  If I put the in the command again,  it asks for a password and again..takes anything I put in it and does nothing.

If I stop the openvpn process at this point and try the command, it does nothing..it wont ask me for anything.